# String Inside an Angular Expression

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have a string inside an Angular expression? For example:

```
<p><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ phone }}</p>
```

Would it be possible to have that `<strong>` tag inside that expression, so `Phone:` isn't rendered to the page, unless something is pulled from the `{{ phone }}` expression?

Hope that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `ng-if="phone"` directive to the `p` element

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-show to show elements only under certain conditions, so in your case you can hide the complete p element if the desired value is not defined using ng-show:
*(or you can use ng-if to completely skip that element as Rahil Wazir mentioned in his comment)*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.phone1 = '1234';
    $scope.phone2 = undefined;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <p ng-if="phone1"><strong>Phone: {{phone1}}</strong></p>
        <p ng-if="phone2"><strong>Phone: {{phone2}}</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this not appear in the HTML if it's hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Or use ng-hide directive too.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Strong tag in AngularJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

Phone: <input type="text" ng-model="phone "><br>

<br>

<p><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ phone }}</p>
</div>

<script>
function personController($scope) {
$scope.phone = "987654321"

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can just use **{{ 'some random string' + x }}**. Here **'x'** is a variable defined on the whichever scope this expression is referring to.

string concatenation will happen as you would expect.